# What algorithm will sort nodes to create the least number of crossing connection lines?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, graph, nodes, graph-algorithm

I have a graph which has parent nodes up top, and layers of child nodes. Each child node can connect to one to many parent nodes.

I'm building a visual representation, and I want to sort all the nodes so that there is the least number of connecting lines that are crossing.

Child nodes should be grouped together as closely as possible. The parents can be re-arranged.

Unoptimized:
[image]

Optimized:
[image]

Another Unoptimized:
[image]

Optimized:
[image]

Comment: This is a relatively complicated problem to code up while covering all "corner cases". You would be better off using a [library for optimizing graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing#Software).

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like I'm going to use Graphviz via [Viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js) to lay this out. From the [demo](http://viz-js.com/) tool I was able to build out my graph, and it laid it out just like I wanted it to be.
Graph:
digraph G {
 A1 -> A2 
 A1 -> D2 
 A1 -> B2 
 B1 -> C2
 C1 -> A2
 C1 -> B2
 A2 -> A3
 A2 -> F3
 B2 -> B3
 B2 -> D3
 B2 -> G3
 B2 -> H3
 C2 -> C3
 C2 -> D3
 C2 -> E3
 D2 -> D3
 D2 -> F3
 D2 -> I3
 B2 -> H3
}